# why we can't get object by value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set red color for all input with `X` value and `small` class.

but this code doesn't work.

```
$('.small[value="X"]').css('border','1px solid #F00');
```

html

```
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo trim($order['dns1']); ?>" class="wd-150 en small"  /><br />
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo trim($order['dns1']); ?>" class="wd-150 en small"  /><br />
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo trim($order['dns1']); ?>" class="wd-150 en small"  /><br />
```

is there any tip?

Comment: you have class `smalltx` but changing on `.small`. Try `$('.smalltx[value="X"]')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the attribute selector, `[...]`, you're inspecting the *attribute* `value`, which is the  value the input was given when created, not its actual value, which is a *property* of the input field.

You'd have to fall back to a filter:

```
$('.small')
    .filter(function() { return this.value == 'X'; })
    .css('border', '1px solid #F00');
```

Answer (score 4):

Attribute selectors (`[]`) will only select elements which had that given attribute value in the markup when the page was loaded or set through `.attr()` which won't work in most cases (user-inputted values).

There's no such thing as a property selector yet so you will need a manual [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$('.small').filter(function() {
    return this.value === "X";
}).css('border','1px solid #F00');
```